# Using the ng-checked value to add to a link

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It's pretty complicated to explain, but I will try to do my best. What I want to achieve is, using the checkbox value (which is my ID) and when one of them (there are many since they are items in a list) is checked I want to use that value and be able to trigger my anchor tag to edit that item.

The checkbox itself

```
<td><input type="checkbox" value="item.iid" ng-checked="item.iid" id="item_{{item.iid}}"></td>
```

The edit link

```
<a href="#/edit/{{item.iid}}"><div class="edit">Edit</div></a>
```

My Edit Controller

```
var EditCtrl = function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, Item) {
    $scope.action = "Update";
    var id = $routeParams.editId;
    $scope.item = Item.get({ id: id });

    $scope.save = function () {
        Item.update({ id: id }, $scope.item, function () {
            $location.path('/');
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: I don't think href will resolve {{item.iid}},use ngHref instead. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Comment: it worked when I had it in a table, but then it becomes to cluttered if every row in the table needs an edit button. This way I try to use one button for all rows and combining it with checkboxes instead so I can also delete them later.

Answer (score 0):

you should use ng-click instead of ng-checked, when a user clicks you should mark current item as checked or unchecked
example below

```
<a href="#/edit/{{lastChecked}}"><div class="edit">Edit</div></a>
<td><input type="checkbox" value="item.iid" ng-checked="amIChecked(item.iid)" ng-click="checkMe(item.iid)" id="item_{{item.iid}}"></td>
```

Here is js

```
var EditCtrl = function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, Item) {
    $scope.action = "Update";
    var id = $routeParams.editId;
    $scope.lastChecked = null;
    $scope.item = Item.get({ id: id });
    $scope.checkMe = function(id){
        if($scope.lastChecked=== id){
            $scope.lastChecked= null;
        }else{
            $scope.lastChecked= id;
        }
    };
    $scope.amIChecked = function(id){
        return $scope.lastChecked=== id;
    };
    $scope.save = function () {
        Item.update({ id: id }, $scope.item, function () {
            $location.path('/');
        });
    };
};
```